# Bluetooth connection in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, eaaccessory

Is it possible to programatically pair an iOS device with a Bluetooth device?
I would have the device's MAC address and also the Bluetooth Pin.

I know it's possible to do on an Android device without any pairing screen/dialogue appears, but can it be done in iOS?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Look for `ExternalAccessory.framework`

Comment: @Larme: Did you find anything to connect and disconnect the paired device using ExternalAccessory api ?